# Is there a diff patch plugin for patching files in Notepad++?

Tags: plugins, diff, notepad++, patch

I know that Eclipse and NetBeans have a plugin so you just e.g. in NetBeans do this:

1. Open the project and right-click on the file or folder you want to patch.
2. Tools > Apply Diff Patch...
3. Browse to and select the patch file you want to apply. > Click "Patch".

Is there some way to do this with Notepad++?

Comment: Can I remind folks that questions about development tools **are** on topic, even NotePad++.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. I guess there isn't one yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! There is now a [Compare plugin for Notepad++.](https://github.com/jsleroy/compare-plugin)

[image: Plugin manager notepad++]
[image: Notepad++ Diff]

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is for producing .patch files rather than for applying them. Would love to be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Here a link to the .patch handler (win)

http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/patch/

You can grab the sources ect...
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm

Any one who's had experience building plugins for notepad++ could probably easily integrate this.
Would be a nice addition, I too am looking for some thing similar, lol NetBeans it is then...

Comment: This answer provides a link to a patch tool, which is completely independent of Notepad++. A hopeless attempt to relate the patch tool to the question is made by saying:  "Someone could probably integrate it with Notepad++" So while this may relate to the topic it doesn't relate to the question.